# GWT, TextField, Alt-Codes and getting an Event

Tags: events, gwt

I am having some trouble with GWT and TextField Events.

I want to program a search field and be able to enter Danish and Swedish Names (i.e. Ø = alt + 0216 ) and update apply a filter/formatter and present life-results.

While normal letters and digits work fine using keyup-events, the alt combination makes it really difficult. Working on FF16 here and there seems to be absolutely no event *AFTER* releasing alt.

Is there even any way to get a simple ChangeEvent for a TextField?

Comment: Keyboard events are a mess in JS across browsers, and GWT events map to underlying events without much twiddling (I don't know for `TextField`, which comes from a 3rd-party lib); I'd suggest you try in pure JS then reformulate your question without GWT and ask with the `js` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it myself. I think it should work using [public void addListener(FieldListener listener)](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/Field.html#addListener%28com.gwtext.client.widgets.form.event.FieldListener%29).

The [FieldListener](http://gwt-ext.com/docs/2.0.4/com/gwtext/client/widgets/form/event/FieldListener.html) has

```
onChange()
```

and

```
onSpecialKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ValueChangeHandler to a TextBox, but it will only fire when the TextBox looses focus.

If I understand your use case correctly, you don't need a KeyUpEvent when ALT key is released. You need to know if ALT key was pressed when another key was released. Native browser events have a flag for it: event.altKey.